# Storing random generated number in a variable, why does the value not change?

Tags: javascript

The first time I type the random variable in the console I get a number between 1 and 10 which is expected. Then every time I retype the random variable it gives me the same number. Why is this?

```
       var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a variable, you should create a function to generate a random number.

```js
const random = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

const number1 = random();
const number2 = random();
const number3 = random();

console.log(number1, number2, number3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also this is useful,

```js
const randomVariable = function () {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
};
randomVariable();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).